# Converting a UITextField String to a Double inside a UITextField Action

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have not been able to convert `hoursWorked` to a double inside a UITextField property I keep getting a "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Double' with an argument list of type '(UITextField!)'"

```
  @IBOutlet weak var hoursWorked: UITextField!

   @IBAction func onEditingChange(sender: UITextField) {
        var hoursWorkedAmount = Double(hoursWorked)
        var salary = hoursWorkedAmount! * 25
        print(salary)
    }
```

I've tried to test everything before hand on playgrounds to get a better understanding of what I'm doing wrong but I keep getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the text field's text, not the text field itself.

Change:

```
var hoursWorkedAmount = Double(hoursWorked)
```

to:

```
var hoursWorkedAmount = Double(hoursWorked.text)
```

Better yet, change it to:

```
var hoursWorkedAmount = Double(sender.text)
```

This way your method acts on the actual text field that sent the event.

Note: I'm not fluent in Swift. You might need a `!` after `text`.

Comment: [UITextField's text property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/text) has type `String?`, so you would indeed need the `!` unless you use optional binding.

Comment: I think that solved my problem but it keeps mentioning that "Variable 'hoursWorkedAmount' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant"

Comment: Then change the variable to use `let`.